# Undefined jQuery in CDHtmlDialog

Tags: jquery, mfc

when I am trying to use `jQuery` it says jQuery is undefine
I included jquery.js before doing anything with jquery.

### My html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/JS/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Shared assets -->        
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ajax/CSS/style.css">        
<title></title>  
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict;
</script> 
</head>
```

---

But when i give the complete path for the `jquery` file it starts working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d:/htmldialog/ajax/JS/jquery.js"></script>
```

problem is i can not give the complete path. In my

```
CDHTMLDialogDlg::OnInitDialog 
Navigate (strUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, consider using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for common libraries. They are cached across pages, and can increase your page's loading time by a decent chunk. Here is the Google CDN for jQuery https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Secondly, it looks like your relative path is most likely off. Is your CSS loading? Where is your actual .html file located.

Unless absolutely necessary to run offline or have a specific jQuery version, go with the CDN.

Comment: The executable I am woking with will run on system which may have internet or may be not. The CSS is loading fine also if I include some other JS file that is also getting loaded for example JS for slider. The HTML is in the same folder and the variable strUrl holds the complete path to the  html

Comment: The path for the html file is "d:/htmldialog/htmldialog.htm" and path for JS and CSS are "d:/htmldialog/ajax/JS/jquery.js" and "d:/htmldialog/ajax/CSS/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is fine with the path. But you have to create a DWORD value in `regedit.exe` under following path with value name as `yourappname.exe` with value `7777`,

32-bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

64-bit:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

For more reference [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation).

Comment: currently the decimal value is 10001 and hex 2711 in the registery

Comment: whether any positive responses? If not use decimal 7777 value, for good performance.

Comment: i tried almost all combination starting from 7777 till 10001 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"htmldialog.exe"=dword:00002711. Their are few more thing like document.getElementById is not working

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks everyone for answering and helping
I got a solution to the problem i mentioned. As WinAppy stated need to add a key in the registry under 
1.[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
2.Need to give the complete path for JS and CSS. This can be done using JAVAScript

```
        var loc = window.location.toString();
        loc = loc.replace("res://", "");
        loc = loc.split("\\").join("/");
        var imageRoot = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf("Debug"));
        imageRoot = imageRoot + "ajax//images//";
        var url = new Array();
         url[0] = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf("Debug")) + "ajax//JS//jquery.js";
         url[1] = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf("Debug")) + "ajax//JS//jquery.jcarousel.min.js";
         url[2] = loc.substr(0, loc.lastIndexOf("Debug")) + "ajax//JS//jcarousel.ajax.js";

         for (i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
             var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
             var script = document.createElement('script');
             script.type = 'text/javascript';
             script.src = url[i];
             head.appendChild(script);

         }

    </script>
```

3.Solution for another problem that document.getElementById not working is call it on
    window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("Title_Bar").src = imageRoot + "Title_Bar.png";
    }
if using default calling in CHtmlDialog. In other words if not using Navigate (strUrl);

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the above suggestions to work, but when I put my JavaScript into my resources along with my html, I got the following to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res:/JS/#2300"></script>
```

Where #2300 is the value of my resource ID referring to my custom resource that contains the JavaScript.  The JS is the custom resource type I created.

Hope that helps someone.